# Is any Joda library method is there to convert Joda.Money to Pennies?

Tags: java, java-money, joda-money, joda-convert

I want to convert Joda.Money to pennies. Is there any Joda library method available?

Sample input:

> USD 233.33

Sample output:

> 23333

Tried below 2 options:

1. tried with `Money.getAmountMinorInt()` and it's returning with multiplies of 100.
2. getAmount * 100

not sure using `getAmountMinorInt` is correct.

Which way of converting is correct or any other library method available to convert it?

Comment: What is wrong with [getAmountMinor](https://www.joda.org/joda-money/apidocs/org.joda.money/org/joda/money/Money.html#getAmountMinor())?

Comment: `.getAmountMinorInt()` seems to be what you are looking for. The method returns the minor units of the currency. For USD, that is pennies.

Comment: `...and it's returning with multiplies of 100.` Maybe you should include an example and how the input is incorrect. The getAmountMinor methods seem to be exactly what you're looking for.